# How to prove the norm of a cross product equals the norm of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

tldr; How do I go about proving:
$$||\vec{b}-proj_{\vec{a}}\vec{b}|| = ||\frac{\vec{a}\times \vec{b}}{||\vec{a}||}||$$

While programming an open source implementation of a [computer vision paper](https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/%7Eraananf/projects/dehaze_cl/), I came across this definition of a distance metric:
$$dist = ||\vec{b}-proj_{\vec{a}}\vec{b}||$$

The metric quantifies how well a line fits some point. The line is defined in vector form $\vec{x} = \vec{p} + t\vec{a}$.  Here $\vec{a}$ is the direction vector of the line and $\vec{b}$ is the vector from point $\vec{p}$ on the line to some point $\vec{w}$. [Here is a plot of the vectors and their relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msHov.png),
where $q$ denotes $\vec{b}-proj_{\vec{a}}\vec{b}$.

I found the second formula $||\frac{\vec{a}\times \vec{b}}{||\vec{a}||}||$, in an already [existing implementation](https://github.com/Tomlk/Dehazing-with-Color-Lines/blob/3f71d428e57460022a56d9569374cd5158a68f85/Patch.cpp), without any further comments. Intuitively, it behaves similarly to the first formula: The numerator will increase when the angle between $a$ and $b$ is larger (as the norm of the cross product equals the area of the parallelogram spanned by the two vectors). The denominator also makes sense, as the result should be independent of the length of $\vec{a}$.  However, I do not have the intuition nor the linear algebra calculus skills to prove the equality. I did [program both](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CgaczjamfULNj40z7hl4sLiWncRtDh6x) and ran them on a large set of problems; they produced the same results. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One property of the cross product is $\|a \times b\| = \|a\|\|b\| \sin \theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$. So the right-hand side is equal to $\|b\| \sin \theta$.

If you draw the vectors $a$ and $b$, and project $b$ onto the span of $a$, then you get a right triangle with hypotenuse $\|b\|$, and legs $\|\text{proj}_a(b)\|$ and $\|b - \text{proj}_a(b)\|$ (see [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Linalg_projection_4.png)), where $\|b - \text{proj}_a(b)\|$ is the leg opposite the angle $\theta$. From the definition of $\sin \theta$ we have $\sin \theta = \frac{\|b - \text{proj}_a(b)\|}{\|b\|}$.

Comment: Such a clean answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you said the norm of the cross product is the area of the parallelogram with side lengths of **a** and **b**. The height of the parallelogram, viewing **a** as the base, is then $b-proj_a b$, resulting from how vector addition and subtraction is defined. Using the formula for the area of a parallelogram the equality follows.